# How to get the data from BehaviorSubject after its completed?

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that returns a `BehaviorSubject` but when I try to use the data I get back from the function I need to use it once all the data is back, is there a way to know when the `BehaviorSubject` is done pulling all the data?

I tried using `.finally` but it never gets called. Here is the code I'm using.

```
getData() {
  let guideList = '';
    this.getChildren(event.node)
      .subscribe(
        function(data) {
          console.log('here');
          guideList = data.join(',');
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log('error');
        },
        function() {
          console.log('done');
          console.log(guideList);
        }
      );
}

getChildren(node: TreeNode) {
  const nodeIds$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  //doForAll is a promise
  node.doForAll((data) => {
    nodeIds$.next(nodeIds$.getValue().concat(data.id));
  });
  return nodeIds$;
}
```

Attached is a screen shot of the console.log[image]

Comment: can you try using `.onCompleted()` of behaviour subject

Comment: you can try to check which is the last element in your `data` array and after it just call `.onComplete()` method of BehaviourSubject

Comment: Would the .onCompleted be called after I subscribe to the call?

Comment: Subscribe take 3 function, first is called everytime `onNext` is called, second is called if `onError` is called, and third is called if `onCompleted` is called.

Comment: `OnNext` is called as many times as you want and every `Observable` ends with either `onError` or `onCompleted` call after which you won't get any more data from it.

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: I updated the call with the onCompleted but it never gets called.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of RxJS you're using but there's `takeLast(1)` operator that might do what you need: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeLast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just collect all the data in the array and only call `next` once the data is all collected.  Even better: don't use a subject at all.  It is very rare that one ever needs to create a subject.  Often people use Subjects when instead they should be using a more streamlined observable factory method or operator:

```
getChildren(node: TreeNode) {
  return Observable.defer(() => {
    const result = [];
    return node.doForAll(d => result.push(d.id)).then(() => result);
  });
}
```